# regex string in python apparently simple but how can I make this work?

Tags: python, regex

I`m trying to write a regex string for Python that helps me at work but I need a bit of help from you. Literally I want to say that a Slinger (beginner) should be paid in between £13.99/H and £15.99/H, I am a beginner and got no clue about it... the problem is that the word slinger can be used in any other contexts and I want to be triggered only when more than one condition applies. (e.g Slinger and 13.50 should trigger but not when the word slinger it is by its own).
I somehow come up with this:

```
((S\/S)|(Slinger\/Signaller)|(Slinger)|(Banksman)|(\£\b1[4-6]\b)|(\b1[4-6]\b\£)|(\b1[4-6]p\/h\b))
```

but it`s not good enough for what I need to achieve as it triggers any slinger text. Any help its much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(edited)

Thanks a lot for your prompt answers guys. To make yourself a better idea, I want to give you an example, so please have a look at the next sentence (message):

"Slinger Required for ongoing work in Central London.
We are currently looking for a CPCS slinger for a project in Bond Street, must be experienced (Blue Card) on working in construction sites and be a skilled slinger.
Salary negotiable upon experience from £13.99/h to 15.99/h (139.99-159.99/day) for a beginner slinger (Red Card)(on a 10 hours program) or  £16.00/H to 18.00/h (£160-£180/day) for a skilled (Blue Card) Slinger. For more information`s please contact the phone number: 02131615139"
(sometimes the rates are given in £/h, somethimes in £/Day.

Thousands of these messages are written on our group with different rates of pay and discussions about slingers (as a word).
I want to filter (match) every message that contain Slinger and a rate between £13.99/h to 15.99/h (139.99-159.99/day) to fall into the "beginer slinger category" and every message that contain slinger and £16.00/H to 18.00/h (£160-£180/day) to fall into "skilled slinger category" but NOT to trigger the word Slinger alone (if in any other context).
I hope this can help you to create yourself an idea of what I want to achieve and any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks a lot guys and be safe.

Comment: If you are parsing some text, and want to extract some matches from it, you should provide it (the text) in your question.

Comment: Can you edit examples of strings to match And also __not__ to match into your question? Have you tried building the regex in increments rather than trying to solve it all in one hit?

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
\b(?:S/S|Slinger/Signaller|Slinger|Banksman) £(?:13\.99|1[45](?:\.\d{2})?)/H\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:S/S|Slinger/Signaller|Slinger|Banksman)`  Match any of the alternatives and a space
- `£` Match literaly
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `13\.99` Match `13.99`
  - `|` Or
  - `1[45](?:\.\d{2})?` Match 14 or 15 with and optional decimal part to match 2 digits. (If you want to match 1 or 2 digits, use `\d{1,2}`)
- `)` Close group
- `/H` Match literally
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ry4SZ2/1)